# java : interface as input parameter in itself

Tags: java, interface, signature

The title is not quite clear, but I didn't see how to explain it in a short sentence.

I have an interface myInterface (This must be an interface, not an abstract, because enum will implement it).
I expect to have an attribute myAttribute (integer) which is not reachable from outside, except for the derivated classes from the interface (protected).
I want a method myMethod that contans myInterface as input parameter. But then, I have trouble when I try to implement it.
The method looks like this

```
boolean myMethod(myInterface interface)
{
return this.myAttribute>interface.myAttribute;
}
```

I can't define "myAttribute" as protected in "myInterface".
If I don't define "myAttribute" in "myInterface", I can't use it in the definition of myMethod, when I implement it in my derivated class : The signature should contain "myInterface" as input parameter, and this one doesn't have any "myAttribute" attribute.
The only solution I have now is to cast "myInterface" in its derivate, but I don't like it (Globally, I don't like casts). Does anyone has another idea?

Comment: you want protected method in interface, it is impossible. use public method or stay with casts

Comment: Generally it makes no sense... Let say you have your final attribute in the interface, then myAttribute > myAttribute will always return false

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

Interfaces can only define (implicitly) `public static final` variables, otherwise said, public **constants**.

What you should do is define a method returning your attribute in your interface, which in turn, its implementing classes will be forced to implement (if they're not abstract).

The method will be implicitly `public`.

This will also enforce the encapsulation of the variable within the implementing classes.

You can then retrieve the value by virtually invoking the getter method on the interface: `myInterface.getMyAttribute()`.

**Edit**

If your scope is to not be able to access the value an instance field outside classes that implement a common interface **at all**, you can proxy you hierarchy by having an abstract class in between the interface and your implementing classes.

In turn, the abstract class would implement none of the interface methods (hence still forcing the concrete classes to implement all), but instead feature a `protected` attribute that the concrete classes would all have access to.

Finally the concrete classes could decide whether or not to let other classes access that field.

Comment: As written, I don't want myAttribute to be reachable from other classes than the derivated one. I prefer then to cast my interface.

Comment: @Hermios your attribute won't be reachable from other classes save for the ones implementing your interface, as long as it's well encapsulated.

Comment: then can you be more explicit? How can I define a method to return my attribute, the method would be public but the attribute is not reachable from other classes?

Comment: @Hermios if primitive, the method will return the **value** of your attribute. If the attribute is an object, you can have your methods returning a copy of the object to prevent unwanted mutability. If instead you really only want a variable shared across the hierarchy with no visibility whatsoever outside, have an abstract class (not) implementing your interface, and a `protected` variable there. Then have the classes formerly implementing your interface (also) extending the abstract class.

Comment: As I said, abstract won't work since my concrete class would be an enum, that cannot extends a abstract class

Comment: @Hermios if you opt for an `enum`, there's only one possible level of hierarchy as you point out, and no proxy `abstract` class. In that case, you **cannot** have an attribute common to your `enum`s implementing the same `interface` without repeating the logic in every `enum` (and you still wouldn't be able to reference that attribute in any way through a reference to the `interface`). Any method declared by your `interface` will be `public`, while every field will be a constant.

Comment: It all boils down to: you cannot derive fields from an `interface`, only implement `public` methods. If the method is `public`, it's accessible to all.